# get random number from pattern with unique digit

Tags: php, random, unique

Let say if pattern is 123456.

In php is it possible to get number exact six digits in length and digit should not repeat more than once in generated no.

```
456136 -- all digit are unique right

56136 -- wrong digit 4 is missing
456436 -- wrong digit 4 repeats
```

Comment: You want to shuffle '123456' into a random order? Or generate a 6-digit number, from scratch, where no digits repeat?

Comment: @Marc Ya it is shuffle. I could have searched for shuffle function instead bitwise shift in php site :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need 1-6 digits

```
str_shuffle('123456');
```

If you need 1-9 digits

```
substr(str_shuffle('123456789'),0,6);
```

[Manual](http://php.net/str_shuffle)

Comment: +1 I didn't know that function existed -- a better solution than re-inventing the wheel like I did ^^

Comment: Also, use the base string `"11223344556677889900"` for up to one repeating digit.

Comment: @Patrick:Problem is 113456 will be more rarely then 123456. is it OK for you?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you 0 repeats:

```
$random = array();
while(count($random) != 6)
{
    $random[] = rand(0, 9);
    $random = array_unique($random);
}
$random = implode('', $random);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by splitting your pattern into an array of digits, using [**`str_split()`**](http://www.php.net/str_split) :

```
$pattern = '123456';
$digits = str_split($pattern);
```

Then, you could use [**`shuffle()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on that array, so its elements are in random order :

```
shuffle($digits);
```

And, finally, you can [**`implode()`**](http://www.php.net/implode) that randomized array back to a string :

```
$result = implode('', $digits);
```

Dumping the content of that variable :

```
var_dump($result);
```

You'll get results like these ones :

```
string(6) "645132"
string(6) "462513"
string(6) "542316"
```

Always six digits, always the digits you specified ; and none used more times than specified in the pattern.

Comment: nice explanation and effective too :).(I treid but unable to address your name using @ symbol)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$nums = array();

while(count($nums)<=6){
    $rand = rand(0,9);
    if(!in_array($rand, $nums)){
         $nums[] = $rand;
    }
}

echo implode('',$nums);
```

#### Demo:

**1st Run:**
http://codepad.org/31AKqeYz
**2nd Run:** http://codepad.org/ckuUQCP3